# What does $Hom(h, B)$ mean in the contravariant functor?

Tags: category-theory, definition, functors, morphism

The [Wikipedia stated that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hom_functor)

> Let C be a locally small category (i.e. a category for which hom-classes are actually sets and not proper classes).

> For all objects A and B in C we define two functors to the category of sets as follows:

> Hom$(-,B):C\rightarrow$ Set

> This is a contravariant functor given by:

> - Hom$(-,B)$ maps each object $X$ in $C$ to the set of morphisms,
>   Hom$(X,B)$

> - Hom$(-,B)$ maps each morphism $h:X\rightarrow Y$ to the function:
>   Hom$(h,B)$:m Hom$(Y,B)\rightarrow $Hom$(X,B)$ given by $g\mapsto
>      g\circ h$ for each $g$ in Hom$(Y,B)$.

But I'm not sure how to intemperate the Hom$(h,B)$ in thus case. $B$ is a functor which is also a morphism, a single object. $h$ is a morphism but not a functor, and it maps the object $X$ in $C$ to some unknown range. I don't understand why Hom$(h,B)$ is possible since, for Hom$(M,N)$, the $M$ and $N$ has to be set. (See: [What does Hom(M,N) mean? Atiyah Macdonald proposition 2.9](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1806658/what-does-homm-n-mean-atiyah-macdonald-proposition-2-9))

What does $Hom(h, B)$ mean in the contravariant functor?

Related:

[The definition of contravariant hom functor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2882341/the-definition-of-contravariant-hom-functor)

[On the definition of the contravariant hom functor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4034400/on-the-definition-of-the-contravariant-hom-functor)

Comment: I'm quoting the same wikipedia page you linked at the top of your post:

$\text{Hom}(–, B)$ maps each morphism $h : X \to Y$ to the function
$\text{Hom}(h, B) : \text{Hom}(Y, B) \to \text{Hom}(X, B)$ given by $g \mapsto g \circ h$ for each $g \in \text{Hom}(Y, B)$ 

What's your confusion?

Comment: "$B$ is a functor which is also a morphism" It is neither. $B$ is just an object of $C$. Also the range of $h$ is irrelevant: Only its domain and codomain are important.

Comment: @BenSteffan Thank you. But If $B$ is an object in $C$ and $Y$ an X an object in $C$, what does Hom$(X,B)$ mean? (Quote: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1806668/603316   "Hom(M,N) refers to the set of A-module homomorphisms from M to N.") I'm think about the set notation, $X=\{\{\}\}$ and $B=\{\{\{\}\}\}$ the only morphism is to send $\{\}$ to $\{\{\}\}$. I don't understand how Hom(Y,B) and Hom(X,B) were possible

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate As quoted by you, $\operatorname{Hom}(X, B)$ is the set of all morphisms $f\colon X \to B$. Thus, in your case, $\operatorname{Hom}(X, B) = \{g\}$ where $g\colon X \to B$ is the unique map.

Comment: @BenSteffan That's what I thought, but isn't that a bit strange? (I wasn't too familiar with the category theory.) Also, in order to make the definition precise, shouldn't it be Hom$(\{X\}, \{B\} )$ so that Hom$(\{X\}, \{B\} ) = \{g\}$ where $g:X\rightarrow B $?

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate Not strange at all. And no, it should not be $\operatorname{Hom}(\{X\}, \{B\})$. $\operatorname{Hom}({{-}}, {{-}})$ takes two objects as input, such as $X$ and $B$. The notation $\{X\}$ does not even make sense in a general category.

Answer (score 1):

Here $Hom(h,B)$ is just a notation, we have that $Hom(-,B)$ is a functor, and so must send objects to objects and morphisms to morphisms (it is like 2 maps in one notation). Thus if $h:X\rightarrow Y$ is a morphism in the category $C$, where $X,Y$ and $B$ live as objects, then $Hom(h,B)$ is a map from $Hom(Y,B)$ to $Hom(X,B)$ (here the $Y$ comes first because the functor is contravariant) which sends a map $f:Y\rightarrow B$ to the map $Hom(h,B)(f)=f\circ h:X\rightarrow Y$.